# Why does Visual Studio Release build break on non-executing code line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When building my c++ program with the default release configuration in Visual Studio 10 I put a break point on a line that should never be reached. What confunded me was that when running the program it stopped at the break point.

The code where the break happens appears below (although creating a minimal project with this function does not produce the same behaviour). Adding a volatile statement and moving the break point to this line makes the execution not break.

Why does the "release debugger"(?) step on this line and trigger the breakpoint when it is nto executed? The code execute continues to the return false statement if I continue stepping after the break.

```
bool BoundingBox::intersects(int32_t xpos, int32_t ypos, int32_t dx, int32_t dy) const
{
    int32_t intersectionX;
    int32_t intersectionY;

    if((dx > 0 && xpos > right)
        || (dx < 0 && xpos < left)
        || (dy > 0 && ypos > top)
        || (dy < 0 && ypos < bot))
        return false;

    if(dx != 0)
    {
        intersectionY = ypos + (left - xpos)*dy/dx;
        if (intersectionY > bot && intersectionY < top)
            return true;
        intersectionY = ypos + (right - xpos)*dy/dx;
        if (intersectionY > bot && intersectionY < top)
            return true;
    }

    if(dy != 0)
    {
        intersectionX = xpos + (bot - ypos)*dx/dy;
        if (intersectionX > left && intersectionX < right)
            return true;

        // Could return false here
        intersectionX = xpos + (top - ypos)*dx/dy;
        if (intersectionX > left && intersectionX < right)
        {
            // volatile int e = 9;
            return true; // !! Code execution will break here
        }
    }

    return false; // Stepping with F10 will move here
}
```

Comment: It could be because the source file and object code are out of sync. Does it keep showing this problem even after a complete rebuilt?

Comment: @QuentinUK: Build > Rebuild: Behaviour persists

Comment: You could find out what is happening by opening an assembly window when the program breaks. The true/false result of the last if-statement is the same as the returned value, it could be returning this value instead of the "true" or dropping down to the "false".

Answer (score 0):

Such behavior is not surprising in a release build. With optimized code there is no longer a precise correspondence between a line of source code and a particular address. So breakpoints and single stepping will be erratic.

Comment: I'm guessing that Watch values can be erratic as well in the same situation?